# Overriding util.format affects util.(other)

Tags: node.js

Exploring NodeJS..

BaseClass.js:

```
const util = require("util");

class BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        this.util = util;
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        console.log( util.format( "%s", "baseclass format" ) );
        console.log( util.isArray( [1,2,3] ) );
        util.log( "baseclass log" );
    }
}

module.exports = BaseClass;
```

SubClass.js:

```
const BaseClass = require("./BaseClass");

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    init() {
        this.util.format = function() { return "subclass format"; }
        this.util.isArray = function() { return "subclass isArray"; }
        this.util.log = function() { console.log( "subclass log" ); }
        super.init();
    }
}

new SubClass();
```

Output (of `node SubClass.js`):

```
subclass format
subclass format
subclass format
```

Hmm. Comment out util.format override in SubClass.js:

```
// this.util.format = function() { return "subclass format"; }
```

Try again. Output (of `node SubClass.js`):

```
baseclass format
subclass isArray
subclass log
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? I'd've guessed that `isArray` and `log` call `format` within the util module but I'm not sure where to look to verify this. `node_modules/node/index.d.ts` isn't really enlightening me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The easiest place to verify this is [the docs for `console.log`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) (emphasis mine):

> #### console.log([data][, ...args])
>
> Added in: v0.1.100
>
> - `data <any>`
> - `...args <any>`
>
> Prints to `stdout` with newline. Multiple arguments can be passed, with the first used as the primary message and all additional used as substitution values similar to printf(3) (**the arguments are all passed to [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args)**).

In the Node.js source you can see where this happens in [`lib/console.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6bdc18c592b9d66fd652a9bdaa53f87486d0a634/lib/console.js#L135-L142) (line 140).

In your code, `this.util` is a reference to the object returned by `require('util')`, so when you replace `this.util.format` you're replacing it for all code, not just the code inside your class.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for your consolation.